# Find the zero sin the unit disk of thic complex function $\sin (1/(1-z))$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the zeros in the disk $|z|<1$ for the function $\sin(1/(1-z))$

Here is my attempt:

I know that $\sin(z) = (e^{iz}-e^{-iz})/2i$ so this expression will be zero when $e^{iz}=e^{-iz}$

Writing $z=x+iy$ i have written $1/(1-z)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ and plugged into $e^{iz}=e^{-iz}$, and writing in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$, have tried to equate the corresponding imaginary and real parts of the exponentials

Nothing nice comes out of this however, and I think there must be an easier way, without splitting up $z$ into cartesian components.

Could someone give me a hint as to where to go? I am self studying a problem set and I don't have solutions.

Thanks

Comment: The zeros of $\sin z$ are $0, \pm \pi, \pm 2\pi,\ldots$.

Comment: thanks, it wasnt really aware that the complex sin only has poles in the real line, which makes things a lot simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\sin(w)=0$ iff there is $k \in \mathbb Z$ such that $w= k \pi$.

Hence

$\sin(1/(1-z))=0$  iff there is $k \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$ such that $1/(1-z)= k \pi$.

Furthermore, for $k \ne 0$:

$1/(1-z)= k \pi$ $\quad $iff $\quad $ $z=1-\frac{1}{k \pi}$